# System of ODE equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So to be honest, I'm really stuck on this problem:

The coupled system of ODEs, represents the coupled evolution of the human civilization and the physical Earths enviroment:

$$dT/dt=a_{11}*T+a_{12}*E$$

$$dE/dt=a_{21}*T+a_{22}*E$$

where:

T - is the planetary temperature change and represent the respons of physical environment

E - is the fossil energy use and represent the human-driven socio-economic development

The problem is:

Consider a scenario of the increasing fossil energy use, what is the sign of $a_{22}$?

I have no idea. I have just recently learned about ordinary differential systems, and have a hard time understanding this particular problem.

Comment: The politically correct idea is probably that energy use increases the economy which increases energy use so that the coefficient is positive. Rising temperature could, in balance, reduce heating more than it increases AC use, so that that coefficient is negative. Any numerical values that might occur there are surely purely fantasy.

Comment: Better present the problem, in $x(t), y(t) and t$ and leave out  the technical terms. Also, this is just a description of something general and not  a particular problem yet.

Comment: Ok, I see. So you @ZAhmed also mean that the coefficient should be positive?

Comment: I would argue positive. If energy use is increasing then $\frac{dE}{dt} > 0$. If $a_{22} < 0$ then as $E$ increases, $\frac{dE}{dt}$ decreases, which would be a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much @KenM!